# jQuery not working on Intranet site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to have jQuery total form data on an internal form. I have used the current code on jsfiddle.net and it worked on there with jQuery 1.6.4.

I have tried multiple different jQuery versions. But I am new to jQuery/javascript in general so I have no idea where to proceed from here.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js">
    var $form = $('#apple-order'),
        $summands = $form.find('.apple'),
        $sumDisplay = $('#total');

    $form.delegate('.apple', 'change', function ()
    {
        var sum = 0;
        $summands.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
        });

        $sumDisplay.text(sum);
    });
</script>


<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="apple-order">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="apple" method="post" action="insert.php">

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>Caramel Apple Order Form</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Employee Name</td>
                    <td>: </td>
                    <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Plain Caramel Apple</td>
                    <td>: </td>
                    <td><input name="plain" type="text" class="apple"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>w/ Snickers</td>
                    <td>: </td>
                    <td><input name="snickers" type="text" class="apple"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>w/ Butterfinger</td>
                    <td>: </td>
                    <td><input name="butter" type="text" class="apple"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>w/ Mini M&Ms</td>
                    <td>: </td>
                    <td><input name="mini" type="text" class="apple"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>w/ Pretzels</td>
                    <td>: </td>
                    <td><input name="pretzel" type="text" class="apple"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><strong>Apples w/ Toppings come with Chocolate Drizzle</strong></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">Total: <span id="total"></span></td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">    </td>
                </tr>


    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have also tried multiple browsers (IE8, Chrome, Firefox)

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: It's not that ancient... sometimes the cost of upgrading isn't worth the benefits.

Comment: @jmoerdyk upgrading to new version has its cost as well :) http://addyosmani.com/jqprovenperformance/

Comment: @Shinigamae The irony is on slide 13.

Comment: @jmoerdyk yup, I didn't deny it as I always start with the latest version of any libraries. Some others just want to grab those they need or they know it works.
And isn't the slide amazing? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to access elements before they exist. Wrap your code in a DOM ready handler. Additionally, if you have a `script` element with a `src` attribute, you can't put code in it. You need two `script` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var $form = $('#apple-order'),

    // etc

});
</script>
```

By default, jsfiddle wraps your code in an onLoad handler, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Your `<script>` tags are laid out incorrectly. You need to separate the tags that load external libraries from inline scripts, as I have shown below. You should also load your Javascript at the bottom of the page, after your HTML is declared.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

<script>
var $form = $('#apple-order'),
    $summands = $form.find('.apple'),
    $sumDisplay = $('#total');

$form.delegate('.apple', 'change', function ()
{
    var sum = 0;
    $summands.each(function ()
    {
        var value = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    });

    $sumDisplay.text(sum);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare all your libraries first

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
...
```

then start coding in another place

```
<script>
// do something
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not actually importing jQuery. Try adding the following before your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will download jQuery from Google's CDN.

Comment: Depending on an external CDN might not be desirable for an intranet site.